# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException'

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, termination

I get this error **once in a while** when my program is running. Most of the time, the app works fine, but every now and then the app will crash and point to the second line in the for loop saying:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection  was mutated while being enumerated.'

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 121; i++) {
        NSLog(@"%i", i);
        [(UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:i] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"hexagon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

What do I do to avoid my program from crashing??

Comment: Does you view has 121 uibuttons?

Comment: Please post the symbolicated crash report or stack trace.

Comment: yes my view has 121 buttons

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to change items in an array while you are looping through the array.

Try making a copy of the subviews to loop through so you can change the original.

```
NSArray *loopingArray = [self.view.subviews copy];

for (int i = 0; i < [loopingArray count]; i++){

    NSLog(@"%i", i);
    if ([self.view viewWithTag:i])
        [(UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:i] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"hexagon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: Where is he looping through the array? Isn't he just using a regular for loop?

Comment: Good call, I missed that. It could be that the system is enumerating the subviews when he happens to change one of them.

Comment: All I need to do is change the picture for the buttons with the tag i.